# Change string from lowercase to the original case

Tags: php, html, string, case-sensitive

Hi all just a quick question 'Probably really simple' but i have a string which i converted to lowercase to search for string in file but now i need to convert the string it found in the file back to it's original string. The following is my code

**PHP**

```php
<?php
        $searchfor = $_SESSION['username'];
        $searchfor = strtolower($username);

        // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');

        // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
        $contents = file_get_contents('posts/contents.php'); 
        $contents = strtolower($contents);
            #$posts = file_get_contents('posts/contents.php');
        //Convert urls to <a> links
        $contents = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/", "<a target=\"_blank\" class=\"external\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $contents);

        //Convert hashtags to twitter searches in <a> links
        $contents = preg_replace("/#([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a target=\"_new\" href=\"javascript:myApp.alert('Hashtag\'s currently not working.');\">#$1</a>", $contents);

        //Convert attags to twitter profiles in &lt;a&gt; links
        $contents = preg_replace("/@([A-Za-z0-9\_\/\.]*)/", "<a href=\"profile.php?username=$1\">@$1</a>", $contents);
        // escape special characters in the query
        $pattern = preg_quote('@'.$searchfor, '/');
        // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
        $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
        // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
           $day = date("l");
           $time = date("h:i A");
           $newDateTime = date('g:i A', strtotime($time));
           $message = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
           echo '<div class="card facebook-card">
                   <div class="card-header no-border">
                    <div class="facebook-name">iCode Mentions</div>
                    <div class="facebook-date">'.$day.' at '.$newDateTime.'</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="card-content">
                     <div class="card-content-inner">'.$message.'</div>
                   </div>
                </div>';
        }
        else{
           echo "No mentions";
        }
        ?>
```

**The file it searches for the string/s**

```plain
<div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Dummy">Dummy</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Wednesday at 11:12 AM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">IT WORKS @ADMIN @DUMMY YES #### YES!!</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Dummy">Dummy</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Wednesday at 11:11 AM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Just testing auto updating notifications @Admin @Dummy</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verifiedPink.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Wednesday at 9:09 AM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Testing mentions detect lowercase and uppercase @admin @Admin</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=RisingDevs">RisingDevs</a><img src="img/VerifiedBLUE.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Wednesday at 9:09 AM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">@Admin �</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=RisingDevs">RisingDevs</a><img src="img/VerifiedBLUE.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Wednesday at 4:51 AM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">@YouriOSHelper Hey bb </div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verifiedPink.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 8:02 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Testing mentions again! @Admin</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verifiedPink.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 7:58 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Just testing mentions   @Admin @YourIOSHelper @cole @Vimdo @Dummy @Dummy2</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verifiedPink.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 7:43 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Hey @YourIOSHelper wud?</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verifiedPink.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 7:42 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Hey @YourIOSHelp wud?</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=YourIOSHelper">YourIOSHelper</a><img src="img/VerifiedLIGHTBLUE.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 7:40 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Hey</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 4:33 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Dear @Hdhdhddndnd you account is being suspended due to a spam name if you wish to unsuspend your account please contact me on Twitter https://twitter.com/JosephShenton_ . Sorry for any inconvenience. </div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 4:13 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Wow This App Is Just Bae am i right? XD</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 3:22 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">
              @Vimdo check out http://twitter.com/JosephShenton_ #iCodeRocks
              </div></div></div> 
<div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=RisingDevs">RisingDevs</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 3:13 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">test</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Dummy">Dummy</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 3:05 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Just perfect love this app!</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
            <div class="card-header no-border">
              <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Vimdo">Vimdo</a></div>
              <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 2:28 PM</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">test - @vimdo_</div></div>
          </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 2:16 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Yes I finally got posts to show up in order of date!</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 2:16 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Ter</div></div>
            </div> <div class="card facebook-card">
              <div class="card-header no-border">
                <div class="facebook-name"><a href="profile.php?username=Admin">Admin</a><img src="img/verified.png" height="17px" width="17px"></div>
                <div class="facebook-date">Tuesday at 2:16 PM</div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner">Test</div></div>
            </div>
```

Now i am really hoping that there is a way to convert is all back to its original casing

Thanks Joseph Shenton :)

Comment: On the line `$contents = strtolower($str);`, where does `$str` come from?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $contents = file_get_contents('posts/contents.php');
    $var = $chontents; //before anything happen to it
    $contents = strtolower($str); //after changing to lowercase
```

you can use $var as it didn't got changed by anything

Comment: Ahmad how do you know from the OP where `$str` came from? The only time we see it, its value is being read: `$contents = strtolower($str);`  We don't see what it is set to.

Comment: i think he get's it from file_get_contents('posts/contents.php');

Comment: yeah i do i just forget to change $str to $contents

Comment: and Ahmad can you please explain the answer a bit more thanks?

Comment: thanks but where would i put it because it is output matches to the `$searchFor` string that is what it echos i want to change the echo output back to it's casing if you understand what i mean @Ahmadghoneim

Comment: you mean weather it's lowercase or upper case?

Comment: yeah so say i had this string `Hi my name is Joseph Shenton` and i convert is to lowercase using `strtolower($str);` which will output `hi my name is joseph shenton` thats ok but once the whole script finishes get the stuff it need i need it to convert the words that had caps in them back to having caps in them

Comment: ok where are you going to output that i mean in your php file

Comment: It goes inside of a div